# How do I start gedit in terminal?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gedit

I did a search for how to start gedit from the terminal. Answers were frustrating to say the least. Finally I happened on the idea of opening gedit with the system monitor on and look for new apps. Voilà. There was `xed`.

Here is the nearest solution: but it did not meet requirements.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gedit

Just to clarify. I was looking for the line to allow me to create a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Are you in a terminal window or a TTY? If a window for a non root gedit @con is essentially correct. If in a TTY on a server without a gui things will be a bit more difficult.

Comment: Just to clarify. I was looking for the line to allow me to create a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Then you should [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/985440/edit) your question. Because we were silly and believed you wanted to "start gedit from the terminal" :)

Comment: Also [include](https://askubuntu.com/posts/985440/edit) the output of `lsb_release -a` to get the best answer for your distro and version.

Comment: If you feel that the answers are not answering your question, you must modify your question, so that we understand what you really want. *Please tell us what you want and answer our questions to make us understand.* Otherwise we can only guess and not really help you.

Comment: Voted to close because `xed` is found in Linux Mint, not in *buntu. OP didn't feel like sharing this information.

Answer (score 1):

You're over thinking it.

To start gedit from the terminal, just type "gedit".

If you have any errors, print them here.

Comment: I am now curious. Why did gedit not work? xed does seem odd.

Comment: leave the error here when typing gedit on terminal

Answer (score 1):

Gedit, as described in your link, is "`Text Editor (gedit) is the default GUI text editor in the Ubuntu operating system.`". If you're not starting `gedit` under the control of a GUI environment, (like a <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-F1</kbd> terminal or a `ssh` connection) `gedit` will NOT work.

Ask the system about editors with `man -k editor` (returns 71 results on my system, YMMV), and ask the packaging system about editors with `apt-cache search editor` (418 results, YMMV).

If you'd describe what you mean by "from the terminal" more precisely, we could help more. For example, if you're connected via `ssh`, and running under a local GUI, `man ssh` and the `-X` or `-Y` options would be suggested.

What are you trying to do? If it's remote and simple, there are `awk`, `sed`, `ed`, `editor`, `ex`, `nano`, `red`, `sed`, `vi`, `vim`, or even `emacs` available.

Answer (score 0):

In xubuntu 16.04 run `xfce4-keyboard-settings`. On the "Application Shortcut" tab click the "add" button. For the command paste `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.gedit.desktop`, click "OK". In the next window press the key combo you prefer. Close the keyboard settings window.